# Create countdown in rowview (Titanium)

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, countdown

I am a beginner in Appcelerator Titanium APP development. From the inspiration of [this](http://cssgallery.info/create-a-countdown-timer-with-titanium-appcelerator/) link I am trying to create a countdown timer to be work in TableRowView as each row have its own time set. And I customize this class to show **Hours** with minutes and seconds.

I created the following code in each TableRowView to execute countdown in list on the fly.

**Code 1**

```
my_timer[timer_index] = new countDown(parseInt(timer_index), parseInt(15), parseInt(50),
function() {
    remainingTime.text = ''+my_timer[timer_index].time.h + " : " + my_timer[timer_index].time.m + " : " + my_timer              [timer_index].time.s;
}, function() {
    //alert("The time is up!");
    }
);
```

my_timer[timer_index++].start();

**my_time** used to push all the instances of countdown timer for each row.

The data is coming from XHR, therefore I created an array literal to hold all instances like in the snippet of code.

**Problem**: when I try to run my app with this code, it shows me an exception saying something like "`time.h` is undefined". However, I defined `time.h` as you can see in code.

Furthermore, I can use this class for multiple countdowns by using **single array**

for example:

```
my_timer[0] = new countDown(2,5,5,function(){
    somelabel1.text = my_timer[0].time.h+":"+my_timer[0].time.m+":"+my_timer[0].time.s;
})
my_timer[1] = new countDown(2,5,5,function(){
    somelabel1.text = my_timer[1].time.h+":"+my_timer[1].time.m+":"+my_timer[1].time.s;
})
```

the above code works perfectly and it has no error. But if I try to use this class in loop and pass index number rather than hard-coded values like in **Code 1**, it shows exception as I stated above.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Desire screen to create with countdown timer in TableRowView]

Comment: maybe you could describe the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THank you for your time and answers. I just solved this problem by customizing CountDown Class

```
var countDown = function(h, m, s, _instance_index, fn_tick, fn_end) {
        return {
            total_sec : h * 60 * 60 + m * 60 + s,
            timer : this.timer,
            instance_index : _instance_index,
            set : function(h, m, s) {
                this.total_sec = parseInt(heart) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(e) * 60 + parseInt(s);
                this.time = {
                    h : h,
                    m : m,
                    s : s
                };
                return this;
            },
            start : function() {
                var self = this;
                this.timer = setInterval(function() {
                    ///alert('running');
                    if (self.total_sec) {
                        self.total_sec--;
                        var hour = parseInt(self.total_sec / (60 * 60));
                        var min = (self.total_sec - (parseInt(hour * (60 * 60))) - (self.total_sec % 60)) / 60;

                        self.time = {
                            h : parseInt(self.total_sec / (60 * 60)),
                            m : parseInt(min),
                            s : (self.total_sec % 60)
                        };
                        fn_tick(self.time.h + ":" + self.time.m + ":" + self.time.s, self.instance_index);
                    } else {
                        self.stop();
                        fn_end();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                return this;
            },
            stop : function() {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
                this.time = {
                    h : 0,
                    m : 0,
                    s : 0
                };
                this.total_sec = 0;
                return this;
            }
        };
    };
```

And call this class by using the following code:

```
 my_timer[items_json.Record.NEW[i].ASSIGN_QUEST_ID] = new countDown(parseInt(n[0]), parseInt(n[1]), parseInt(n[2]), items_json.Record.NEW[i].ASSIGN_QUEST_ID, function(curr_time, instance_index) {
                                        questTime[instance_index].text = 'TIME LEFT ' + curr_time;

                                    }, function() {
                                        //alert("The time is up!");
                                    });
                                    my_timer[items_json.Record.NEW[i].ASSIGN_QUEST_ID].start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I had to guess, which I do have to guess because you didn't give us a complete example or even a description of your problem...

Gut instinct is you're looping through to create the rows, referencing a mutable variable (remainingTime) as you do so in a nested function. But when you move on to the next item in the loop, remainingTime changes. So when the nested function references it, it's not the same as what you originally specified, so only the last  timer is updating.

This is demonstrated by the following code, which alerts "3" three times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(i);
    }, 100);
}
```

If you don't know why, or how to fix it, then I suggest you spend some more time cuddled up by a fire with a cup of joe and a good book on JavaScript.